# Airflow DAGs are somtime missing

Tags: airflow

> Previously, airflow dags were seen well without problems.
>
> However, today, there was a problem after installing the
> 'apache-airflow[spark]' plugin and moving the airflow directory to
> /opt/sub.
>
> After adding the "DAG" file, run the scheduler daemon and it comes out
> well at first.
>
> However, when you refresh the page or move the tab, the DAG sometimes
> disappears from the WEB UI.
>
> Sometimes it appears in the WEB UI, so there doesn't seem to be a
> problem with setting up the DAG directory.
>
> What's the problem?

**ADD. Moving the airflow directory to the home directory solved it. What do we need to do to move to /opt?**

Comment: Is the path in /opt mentioned as Dag directory in airflow.cfg?

Comment: @YayatiSule yes, I'm suspicious of db. I am using mysql as db of airflow, and when db is initialized, it operates normally. Why is this happening?